# Check whether element from variable has a refference in current DOM

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

Assume I have an element in a variable:

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0] 
// here can be any kind of getting element, e. g. React ref, Chrome's devtools $0, etc.
```

At some point of time my markup is changing (like in SPA), and element from variable has been removed from DOM, but it still available in the `element` with all properties, such as `parentElement`, etc.

The question is: how to check, if my DOM element from `element` is present in DOM?

I tried to check the `element.getBoundingClientRect()`, and yes, there are some differences: element that removed from DOM has all the zeroes in his bounding rect. But there is one thing: element with `display: none` also has all the zeroes in its bounding rect, despite of it is still presents in the DOM (physically, lets say). This is not acceptable in my case, because I need to differ hidden element from removed element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) for this purpose

```js
function contains() {
  const result = document.body.contains(element);
  console.log(result);
}

const element = document.getElementById('app');
contains();

element.classList.add('hide');
contains();

element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
contains();
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">App</div>
```

Comment: God bless you! Thanks a lot :)